# How to iterate through the result of MySQL query in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying push the result of mysql query into an array. It works fine. But when I `console.log` the array, it returns two instances of the array, the first instance with just one element, and the second instance with all of the expected elements. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I need help.

Here's is me code:

```
let query = "SELECT public_id FROM video_records WHERE frequency = 3"
connection.query(query, (error, result)=>{
    if(result){
        let returnedIds = []
        Object.keys(result).forEach(key=>{
            returnedIds.push(result[key].public_id)
            console.log(returnedIds)
        })
```

and here's is my result:

```
[ 'tmglo0ilcz1earf7dmeg' ]
[ 'tmglo0ilcz1earf7dmeg', 'idjdzqc7juxhvkfmoebb' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not two instances, it's simply the value of the array during that iteration. Move the console log outside the forEach.